# How can i change automatically the name of an object?

Tags: java

I'm building an application where i can create new users and after look the information about the users. I wanted to save all the information of the user in an object and after by this way i could look the information of the user.

```
public class Aplicacion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Menu1 menua = new Menu1();
        menua.showMenu1();
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu1 {
    public void showMenu1() {
        Scanner input1= new Scanner(System.in);
        Menu1 menua = new Menu1();

        System.out.println("1) Crear usuario nuevo.");
        System.out.println("2) Ver usuarios ya existentes.");

        String e1 = input1.nextLine();

        switch(e1) {
        case "1":
            Usuarios usuario = new Usuarios(); //Here i want to change the "usuario" everytime i want to build a new user.
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre: ");              
            break;
        case "2":
            break;
        default:
            menua.showMenu1();
            System.out.println("Error.");

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, variable names exist at compile time. At runtime they're gone and you can't change them (nor do you need to). Look into using a `Map<String, Usuarios>`.

Comment: At the moment of compilation, all `alphanumerical tokens` (variable names) get changed into some numerical tokens used by the `JVM`.

Comment: what exactly are you asking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather an Changing a Object Name try to create an array of objects.

```
   Usuarios[] usuario = new Usuarios[100];
```

By this way you can create a predefined set of objects and then use it in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of objects.

For every "create", you can increament index and store data in object.

While viewing those,

```
for(i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++) {
   show(object[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at storing the users in a permanent storage like Database or file system. Each time the user is created, it should be written to permanent storage. This will also involve checking if the user being created already exists or not.

This is based on the assumption that the code is not complete and somewhere, you are taking more inputs to create a user, else its an empty object.